# how to fix loading scripts in child theme?

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

[image: this is the directory]I am trying to integrate an animation in my Wordpress home page, for this I am trying to load scripts from "skrollr" library, but my styles and scripts don't load.

this is the code I added is function.php in the child theme:

```
function add_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/main.css' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'skrollr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skrollr.min.js', '', '', false);
}
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts');
```

and these are the errors that I get from the console: 
[image]

Comment: replace **get_template_directory_uri()** with **get_stylesheet_directory_uri()** and add '/' before 'main.css'

Comment: thanks for your reply but still have these errors:

Comment: can you post an image of your theme directory or can you show me via teamviewer? I want to help you to resolve this issue.

Comment: Yes sure I can share it with you via teamviewer

Comment: knock me here sbbrhs@gmail.com when you available to share teamviewer

Answer (score 1):

You are using a child theme here, it means that you should use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to get the child theme's directory.

So, in your case, `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` will return:

```
localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/x-child/
```

and `get_template_directory_uri()` will return:

```
localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/x/
```

Use this to build your paths. Also, pay attention that you need to include a forward slash before your style/script's name, since these functions do not provide a trailing slash:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/main.css' );
```

Which will return:

```
localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/x/main.css
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I corrected it but the errors still remain

Comment: Then I doubt the problem is with your functions, if you have build the proper paths and it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
function add_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/images/main.css' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'skrollr', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/skrollr.min.js', '', '', false);
}
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts');
```